# How to use both enter button and onclick(mouse click) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trigger `ajaxFunction()` on both mouse click and "enter key" on submit button. Below is my code

```
<html>
   <body>
      <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">

         //Browser Support Code
         function ajaxFunction() {
            var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

            try {
               // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
               ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {

               // Internet Explorer Browsers
               try {
                  ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
               } catch (e) {

                  try {
                     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  } catch (e) {
                     // Something went wrong
                     alert("Your browser broke!");
                     return false;
                  }
               }
            }


            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {

               if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
                  var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
                  ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
               }
            }


            var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;

            var queryString = "?wpm=" + wpm ;


            ajaxRequest.open('GET', 'ajax-example.php' + queryString, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
         }

      </script>
<script>
      const textbox = document.getElementById("wpm");
      textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
          if (event.key === "Enter") {
              document.getElementById("cli").click();
          }
      });
    </script>
      <form name = 'myForm'>

         Max WPM: <input type = 'text' id = 'wpm' /> <br />


         <input type = 'button' id="cli" onclick = 'ajaxFunction()' value = 'Query MySQL'/>
      </form>

      <div id = 'ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I get on pressing enter key like

> http://localhost/myphp/ajax.html?
>   with a blank page

`onclick` works fine. but strangely onclick doesn't work for `<input type = 'submit' id='cli' onclick = 'ajaxFunction()' value = 'Query MySQL'/>` but works for `<input type = 'button' id='cli' onclick = 'ajaxFunction()' value = 'Query MySQL'/>`

Comment: It probably depends on the browser, but using `keyup` instead of (deprecated) `keypress` might make a difference. Side note: `onlick` is my favorite event name typo :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  const textbox = document.getElementById("wpm");
  textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
          document.getElementById("cli").click();
      }
  });
</script>
```

at this script run time
'wpm' has not been generated yet

so try to another place at 'wpm'generated

try this. You can see the difference between submit and button

```
<script>
  const textbox = document.getElementById("wpm");
  textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = 'test msg';
          alert('test');
          document.getElementById("cli").click();

      }
  });
</script>
```

---

try

```
<script>
  const textbox = document.getElementById("wpm");
  textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
          event.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById("cli").click();

      }

  });
</script>
```

when you pressing enter and input cursor in form. default trigger submit.
cancel default action

Comment: In fact, localhost is your computer, others can't connect.  When type=submit you will reload page and loss result   but type=button didn't reload

Comment: MySQL data is also in localhost also enter key is not working in both case

Comment: When you press enter.Did you focus to input(wpm)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand I places after forms tag

Comment: The Listener is for wpm , so input cursor must focus to wpm

Comment: After pressing enter input cursor is not there in form. Actually results appear and suddenly vanish

Answer (score 1):

Your event listener script for enter key press gets executed before input element with id 'wpm' is defined in the dom probably because your dom manipulation script is preventing document being parsed.

Try placing this script just before body closes , like so :

```
  <div id = 'ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
  <script>
  const textbox = document.getElementById("wpm");
  textbox.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
          document.getElementById("cli").click();
      }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your script.

```
var input = document.getElementById("wpm");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            document.getElementById("cli").click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

**Using javascript**:

`<input type = 'text' id = 'wpm' onkeypress="return ajaxFunction()`" />

**Using jQuery**:

```
$('.#wpm').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#cli').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: OP's code does not using jQuery and the question is not tagged jQuery

Comment: @cat  I've updated my answer. Thanks for drawing my attention.